# Unable to check for already existing primary key

Tags: php, sql

I have 10 tables for 10 php forms. I am using one primary key and passing it to all other pages in session and in corresponding tables using that as foreign key. My problem is whenever I check on the page if that key record exist or not It always display record exist as value has already been passed.

I have another problem.. i want to make update query somewhat like

```
"UPDATE table SET '.$column.' ='.$value.', WHERE id=".$id." ";
```

Where, the column should only be array of only data that is altered without affecting remaining columns and values, and updating all values in one update query. Thank you in advance.

Comment: where is your checking codes?

Comment: Is that the code you have? If you use single equal you will override the $_POST index. You should have two equals to verify the equality.

Comment: Check whether the session value is updated or not?

Comment: what you get as `value` parameter when you check your html code from browser? `$_POST['noces']=$_SESSION['noces'];` outside of php isn't working... update your question and provide more relevant code samples.

Answer (score 1):

Did you start the page with:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
```

This is needed for the Sessions to work, if you are using a `$_SESSION` variable. Hope it helps.

Comment: please update your question rather then writing your code in comment.

Comment: Welcome. How did you do? What was the issue?

Comment: Can you post the DB Dump from phpMyAdmin? We can help.

Comment: @PraveenKumar  thank u n sorry i did nt send u file as i sorted it out ....  solution to my first problem was i was calling function t o check value exist or not at wrong place . for second it was hit and trial.. thank u